# Cannot enable argument names in debug symbols

Tags: java, debugging, compilation, decompiler

I need my application to be compiled at very least with method argument names in order for `SpEL` (Spring Expression Language) to work.

I use Ant's `javac` task with debug information enabled as follows

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src;gen" destdir="build/compiled" deprecation="on" target="1.7" source="1.7" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" verbose="false" classpathref="project.classpath" encoding="utf-8" />
```

I am looking for evidence that argument names are present in the output jar.

Currently my only evidence, by using Eclipse decompiler, is that this information is **not** present.
I am using Enhanced Class Decompiler plugin

Source code:

```
public interface UserManager extends BaseManager<DBUser>
{

    List<Localizable> getPasswordPolicyDescription();

    void checkIfExists(String id);

    DBUser create(String id, String userName, String email, String cultureId, String parentId, LocalDate accountExpirationDate,
                  LocalDate passwordExpirationDate, String password, boolean enabled)
            throws PasswordPolicyException, UserAlreadyExistsException;

    DBUser create(String id, String completeName, String email, String cultureId) throws PhoenixWarningException;

    DBUser update(String id, String completeName, String password, String email, String cultureId, String parentId, boolean enabled,
                  LocalDate accountExpirationDate, LocalDate passwordExpirationDate, Collection<? extends String> assignedRoles)
            throws PasswordPolicyException;

    DBUser update(String id, String completeName, String password, String email, String cultureId, String parentId, boolean enabled,
                  LocalDate accountExpirationDate, LocalDate passwordExpirationDate, String... assignedRoles)
            throws PasswordPolicyException;
```

Loading the same class from a jar with Eclipse decompiler

```
public interface UserManager extends BaseManager<DBUser> {
    List<Localizable> getPasswordPolicyDescription();

    void checkIfExists(String arg0);

    DBUser create(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4, LocalDate arg5, LocalDate arg6,
            String arg7, boolean arg8) throws PasswordPolicyException, UserAlreadyExistsException;

    DBUser create(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) throws PhoenixWarningException;

    DBUser update(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4, String arg5, boolean arg6,
            LocalDate arg7, LocalDate arg8, Collection<? extends String> arg9) throws PasswordPolicyException;

    DBUser update(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4, String arg5, boolean arg6,
            LocalDate arg7, LocalDate arg8, String... arg9) throws PasswordPolicyException;
```

If I try to load any Spring framework class into the decompiler I get variable names correctly, and comments too!!!

```
/**
 * Interface that encapsulates event publication functionality.
 * Serves as super-interface for {@link ApplicationContext}.
 *
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @author Stephane Nicoll
 * @since 1.1.1
 * @see ApplicationContext
 * @see ApplicationEventPublisherAware
 * @see org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent
 * @see org.springframework.context.event.EventPublicationInterceptor
 */
public interface ApplicationEventPublisher {

    /**
     * Notify all <strong>matching</strong> listeners registered with this
     * application of an application event. Events may be framework events
     * (such as RequestHandledEvent) or application-specific events.
     * @param event the event to publish
     * @see org.springframework.web.context.support.RequestHandledEvent
     */
    void publishEvent(ApplicationEvent event);

    /**
     * Notify all <strong>matching</strong> listeners registered with this
     * application of an event.
     * <p>If the specified {@code event} is not an {@link ApplicationEvent},
     * it is wrapped in a {@link PayloadApplicationEvent}.
     * @param event the event to publish
     * @since 4.2
     * @see PayloadApplicationEvent
     */
    void publishEvent(Object event);

}
```

Question(s)

- Is my Ant invocation correct?
- How can I get evidence that arguments are packaged correctly into the jar?

I jave tried `javap -v UserManager.class | grep userId` but nothing displayed. I was assuming that parameter name userId would have been displayed somewhere

### Example

Consider the following Spring Framework class `AsyncListenableTaskExecutor`

```
public interface AsyncListenableTaskExecutor extends AsyncTaskExecutor {

    ListenableFuture<?> submitListenable(Runnable task);

    <T> ListenableFuture<T> submitListenable(Callable<T> task);

}
```

As you can see the argument names are `task`. I have extracted `AsyncListenableTaskExecutor.class` from Spring core's jar in my classpath. Then executed

```
$ javap -v AsyncListenableTaskExecutor.class
```

In the output I can't see evidence of the argument name `task`

```
Classfile /Z:/spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/task/AsyncListenableTaskExecutor.class
  Last modified 23-gen-2018; size 656 bytes
  MD5 checksum 3c1894a7d3d48ce79991d55c4984dcf7
  Compiled from "AsyncListenableTaskExecutor.java"
public interface org.springframework.core.task.AsyncListenableTaskExecutor extends org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_INTERFACE, ACC_ABSTRACT
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #12            // org/springframework/core/task/AsyncListenableTaskExecutor
   #2 = Class              #13            // java/lang/Object
   #3 = Class              #14            // org/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor
   #4 = Utf8               submitListenable
   #5 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Lorg/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
   #6 = Utf8               Signature
   #7 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Lorg/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture<*>;
   #8 = Utf8               (Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Lorg/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
   #9 = Utf8               <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>(Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable<TT;>;)Lorg/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture<TT;>;
  #10 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #11 = Utf8               AsyncListenableTaskExecutor.java
  #12 = Utf8               org/springframework/core/task/AsyncListenableTaskExecutor
  #13 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #14 = Utf8               org/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor
{
  public abstract org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture<?> submitListenable(java.lang.Runnable);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Lorg/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT
    Signature: #7                           // (Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Lorg/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture<*>;

  public abstract <T extends java.lang.Object> org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture<T> submitListenable(java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>);
    descriptor: (Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Lorg/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT
    Signature: #9                           // <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>(Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable<TT;>;)Lorg/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture<TT;>;
}
SourceFile: "AsyncListenableTaskExecutor.java"
```

Comment: There are no parameters in your Spring example, so we can't see that they're actually being resolved.  Since the Javadoc comments are present, I'm guessing it's _not_ actually being decompiled, but it's showing you the actual sources instead (possibly pulled from Maven).  As far as I know, parameter names are not stored for interfaces prior to Java 8, which would be classfile version 52.  Your example looks like it was compiled for Java 6.

Comment: @MikeStrobel you are correct for Java version (Spring 4.x is compiled for Java 6 while I though 7), but I can't see how "there are no parameters in my Spring example" in a method called `submitListenable(Runnable task)`. Maybe I must pick a class rather than an interface and repeat the example. I will amend my question accordingly

Comment: I was referring to the `ApplicationContext` example.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was writing the correct example but picked up the wrong part of the code. By the way Maven is banned in our company, we use... sigh... Ivy